# How to open a modal dialog in angular 6

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular6, bootstrap-modal

I've created a modal dialog in angular 6, and this dialog should be displayed when I click on a cell in the table.

The modal dialog component template code is provided below.

```
<div #leaveModal class="modal fade" id="leaveModal"   tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Leave Classroom</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            &times;
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure you want to leave the classroom?</p>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-right  lg" data-dismiss="modal" >
               Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom lg mr-2 float-right" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="onLeave()">Leave</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The oncell click event code is as given below

```
onCellClicked($event) {
  this.selectedRowIndex = $event.rowIndex;
  console.log("[userDetailsComponent] :: onCellClicked():: selectedRowIndex::" + this.selectedRowIndex);
  console.log($event);


  if ($event.colDef.headerName == 'Leave Classroom') {
    this.leaveModal.open('lg');
```

In addition, there is a method called `open()` in the modal dialog class, but upon calling it displays the error:

> ERROR TypeError: "this.leaveModal.open is not a function

Could you please explain, what is the error here and how to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use jQuery. `$('#leaveModal').modal('show');`

Comment: Have you defined the @viewchild for your model file?

Comment: you cannot use `this.leaveModal.open('lg');`. because that modal you are using is not a component. so do it in html(data-target) or use jQuery

Comment: Yes . I defined @viewchild at the begining.

Comment: another way is ng-bootstrap

Comment: @jasonvuriker I did as you adviced. But got below given error .  ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__(...).modal is not a function

Comment: is jQuery installed?

Comment: yes jQuery installed

Comment: `declare let $: any;` among component imports

Comment: Now there is no any error in the console. But modal pop up not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

For opening modals, you can use `NgbModal` and use it quite efficiently.
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

```
<ng-template #content let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Profile update</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="dateOfBirth">Date of birth</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="dateOfBirth" class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" ngbDatepicker #dp="ngbDatepicker">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="dp.toggle()" type="button"></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Save</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>

<hr>

<pre>{{closeResult}}</pre>
```

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-basic',
  templateUrl: './modal-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdModalBasic {
  closeResult: string;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a modal build as component?

Comment: Hii @IndeewarieBandara We show the template #content as the modal content. So this is not a modal build as component. We can also add component as modal by passing out component in place of template.

Comment: Hi Saluja, Could you please tell how this component can be called outside?

Answer (score 1):

```
component.html

<div #leaveModal class="modal" id="leaveModal" [class.d-block]="show" [class.d-none]="!show"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="false">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Leave Classroom</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" (click)="closeModalBox()" data-dismiss="modal">
            &times;
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure you want to leave the classroom?</p>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-right  lg" (click)="closeModalBox()" data-dismiss="modal" >
               Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom lg mr-2 float-right" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="onLeave()">Leave</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>



Component.ts:


export class AppComponent  {
  show: boolean;


  openModalBox() {
    this.show = true;
  }

  closeModalBox() {
    this.show = false;
  }
}





You Can simply play with css in modal popup
```

Comment: A couple things are missing from this - the backdrop that hides the underlying content while the modal is open - it also needs a focus trap for keyboard users - the focus should not leave the modal while it's open. It would be nice to see a working example of this - maybe I'll make one...